# Is there any collation to differentiate 'е' and 'ё' in case insensitive way?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Mongolian alphabet has 35 letters including those 'е','ё' letters. [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_Cyrillic_alphabet). And in Mongolian 'ес' and 'ёс' are different words different meaning. But `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is thinking it is same. But it is not. `utf8mb4_bin` is not suitable because of case sensitivity. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a collation that is accent sensitive but case insensitive, use `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`.

From [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Release Notes :: Changes in MySQL 8.0.2 (2017-07-17, Development Milestone)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-2.html):

> - MySQL now supports a new collation, `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`, for the `utf8mb4` Unicode character set. This collation is accent sensitive and case insensitive. It is similar to the default utf8mb4 collation (`utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`) except that the default collation is accent insensitive.

Comment: Before version 8.0, you had 2 choices:  insensitive on both case and accents _or_ sensitive on both case and accents.  So, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. But currently using mariadb 10.3 here is not support for _ai_ci charset. 

BTW in Mongolian е, ё totally different. not accent only difference.